# Call a method of class inside a thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, class, methods

How can I call a method of class inside a thread? I have a simple method of class and a simple thread... How can I execute de method inside a Thread? Follow the code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include<thread>

using namespace std;

class Airplaine{
      public:

      int vel = 0;

      void impress(){ cout << "my impress";} // meu método
};

int main(){

        Airplaine *av1=new Airplaine();

       thread first(meu_method_impress()_here); // my method impress inside a thread

       first.detach();

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are several ways to do what you're asking, I'd do the following with a lambda.
`thread first ([&av1](){av1->impress();});`
The main issue you're going to have with something like you have is everything going out of scope before the impress actually gets executed...

Comment: You're right... doesn't work... compiler is ok, but nothing is impress in console; cout doesn't work.. I think it's about scope too... other way?

Comment: main() ends before thread gets time to work. This is a dublicate, there are questions like that. You haveo stop program from exiting before wprker threads are done

Comment: If its just to prove that its in a different thread, add `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` . if Its for a real program, you usually will have a framework where there is a function tick, async loop, or a wait for character to quit (getline could work). lots of other questions have an answer

Comment: @mrsoliver It will work if you store the `av1` pointer inside the lambda (preferrably with a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr`), and make sure `main()` does not exit before the thread finishes (use `join()` instead of `detach()`).

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for you, g19fanatic and Swift Friday Pie... It works now... I add a long loop while and works... now I adapt the code.. I'm very happy...

Comment: Thanks Remy Lebeau... Join in specific case it's ideal....

Comment: std::thread uses std::invoke syntax. A good resource, if you can spare the hour, is the YouTube video by Stephan T. Lavavej on std::functional.

Comment: Amazing information invoke syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compliment the answer of @Pete, you can bind the member function and feed your thread just like a normal function which accepts the object as its argument.

```
Airplaine* av1 = new Airplaine;
std::function<void(Airplaine*)> func = std::bind(&Airplaine::impress, std::placeholders::_1);
std::thread first(func, av1);
first.join();
```

`functional` header is needed.

Or you can use a lambda function:

```
auto f = [](Airplaine* av) {av->impress(); };
std::thread first(f, av1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The thread constructor is pretty smart. Just tell it which member function to call and give it an object to call the function on:

```
Airplane *av1 = new Airplane;
std::thread first(&Airplane::impress, av1);
first.join(); // wait for thread to finish
```

Or, in a more C++-like style:

```
Airplane av;
std::thread first(&Airplane::impress, av);
first.join(); // wait for thread to finish
```

Or, if the member function modifies the object and you need to see those modifications after the thread finishes, pass the object by reference:

```
Airplane av;
std::thread first(&Airplane::impress, std::ref(av));
first.join(); // wait for thread to finish
```